# Multiple source locations for java project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

Can we specify multiple source locations as we can in ant build files in an eclipse java project. For example I have the following directory structure:

```
src1/com/mycompany/myproject/mypackage/*
src2/com/mycompany/myproject/mypackage/*
```

Java Files in  both src folders have the package name as `com.mycompany.myproject.mypackage`
`.java` files from src1 use `.java` files from src2 as well. However when I use my ant build xml file to import the project in eclipse only a single src is found under the project's `Properties->Resource->LinkedResources` can be found and the other source location is ignored. Is this a bug in eclipse? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Right click on your project in `Eclipse` -> `Properties` -> `Java Build Path` -> `Source`. Here you can specify your source folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a solution. Even though exporting directly from the ANT build file does not import from two locations we can do the following steps:

```
Right click project -> Build Path -> Link source -> Provide name and location of linked folder
```

This allows adding of a second folder with similar package structure and hence allows importing files. Hope this helps anyone with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse:

> Right Click on your Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path.. ->
>   Source Tab -> Add Folder ..

Hope this helps.

Comment: It only allows adding a folder relative to the current folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple source folders under the Source tab in Java Build Path of an Eclipse project. PROJECT_LOC refers to the location of the entire project, not its source folders. So you can point to the source folders using:

- ${project_loc}/src1
- ${project_loc}/src2
- and so on

Comment: The sources are linked files they are not inside the project location which might be in the home/workspace/ directory

Comment: Sorry, I missed the LinkedResources part. You are right, there is no built-in variable for linked resources, and they don't show up under the project location. The only solution I can see is to define a custom variable that points to the external location and use it, if you don't want to use a hard-coded value.

Comment: I found a solution. Perhaps I was not able to convey my problem clearly. Please have a look.